How to do AutoFill in Excel with OpenXml or ClosedXml?
In our organisation, people use an Excel spreadsheet with tabular data and a few formulas, which I need to connect to a data provider in C#. With OpenXML, or even better, ClosedXml, we can create or update Excel documents using C# code. However, there is one feature that I cannot yet do in C#, and that is copying a formula to other rows with automatic update of the cell references. The formula looks like this in a cell on row 5:
=IFS(P5=$B$24,$E$24,P5=$B$25,$E$25,P5=$B$26,$E$26

The builtin library function IFS is called with the value in cell P5, and a lookup table in fixed cells in columns B and E, and rows 24-26.
In Excel, it is very easy to add (insert) a new row below row 5, and to copy the formula to this new row by dragging the lower-left corner of the cell with the mouse. The formula is automatically changed to refer to P6 instead of P5, while the cell references with dollar signs are kept unchanged (absolute reference).
For copying a formula in C#, I have not found a way to automatically update P5 to P6.
In Excel, using the macro recorder, I found the following commands:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Auto fill range
    selectedSheet.getRange("C3").autoFill("C3:C5", ExcelScript.AutoFillType.fillDefault);
}

This is in another Excel sheet. It basically takes the content from C3, and copies it to the next two rows: C4 and C5, using command autoFill . It does update the references as described above.
I have not found an autoFill feature in ClosedXml, but there is one in OpenXml:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.vml.spreadsheet.autofill?view=openxml-3.0.1
but the problem is that I don't have any idea how to use this. There is no code example. Google did not find examples either.
I did write a bit of OpenXml code that reads a cell value, but fails to write one:
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

public void UpdateExcel(string FileNameXlsx)
{
    var isEditable = true;
    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = 
        SpreadsheetDocument.Open(FileNameXlsx, isEditable, new OpenSettings()))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
        Workbook workbook = workbookPart.Workbook;
        Sheet sheet = workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First();
        WorksheetPart wsPart = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
        Worksheet ws = wsPart.Worksheet;
        Cell cell_L5 = ws.Descendants<Cell>().First(c => c.CellReference == "L5");
        Cell cell_L6 = ws.Descendants<Cell>().First(c => c.CellReference == "L6");
        cell_L6.CellFormula = cell_L5.CellFormula;
        document.Save();
    }
}
    

The minor problem is how to write this code in a simpler way, and how to write a value to a cell.
The main problem is how to get the autoFill feature in this code.
The reason to try to get the autoFill to work is that we want to separate concerns: the "user" is responsible for the actual formula in the first data row, and I as a developer am responsible to create more rows with data from a database, and using the formula that happens to be present in the first data row. I am in a sense using the input Excel as a template. Of course, I could write correct formula's in all rows if the formula above would be stable, however, it is foreseen that the user(s) may actually alter the formula, and my system should work with any formula that is in the first datarow. Admittedly, this is kind of strange and low-tech, but, for now, this is the situation, and, if possible, I could make people really happy with the autoFill feature.

You can do this in ClosedXML by retrieving the cell.FormulaR1C1 (which is relative by nature) and setting the target cells' .FormulaR1C1 property accordingly.

That's how to set the formula in a cell, but it's not autofill.

@scotthannen It does solve this statement, though: For copying a formula in C#, I have not found a way to automatically update P5 to P6.

I looked at my problem more closely, and the formulas seems to adjust when rows are inserted with ClosedXml. Perhaps this is different from AutoFill, but it does solve my problem.

The Autofill you linked to in OpenXML isn't the same autofill by which we repeat data or formulas across cells. It's about the color and style of cells.

This element specifies that the object’s fill properties are automatically provided by the application and are not overridden with a specific fill color or style.

You won't be able to autofill data or formulas with either OpenXML or ClosedXml. The reason is that autofill isn't something that a worksheet contains. It's something that the Excel application does in response to a user telling it to autofill. Neither OpenXML nor ClosedXml can behave as a macro and perform these sorts of user interactions. It's sort of like telling OpenXML that you want to paste data from the user's clipboard. You can do that in the app. You can't do that when you're bypassing the application and interacting directly with the underlying XML files.
You can write code to populate cells, but unlike Excel's autofill, which figures out what to put in each cell, your code will have to decide exactly what to enter in each cell. So it wouldn't be autofill. It would just be writing code to put data or formulas in cells.

I hoped for a more positive answer, but you sound convincing. Thanks! The positive side is that this is an argument for a solution without Excel, because in fact C# (or javascript, or sql) can do math just great
